# Applying the name attribute to text

Tags: javascript, c#, sql

I was wondering if there was another way of giving names to my strings, something like you do in the input tag.

```
<input name="inpName" type="text" value="@ViewBag.Name" />
```

this would give me a name that I can refer back to when for example when I want to write code in cs, in this case controllers for my website to execute SQL commands such as UPDATE or INSERT INTO.

But I am wondering if there is another way of giving a name to a text element instead of having to use the input tag.

As an example, if I wanted to use a INSERT INTO command but before that I wanted to display the text on a separate cshtml page to make sure everything is correct as to what is about to be inserted into the database.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer;

I put the ViewBag as I would like it to be, in a text element.

```
<h1>@ViewBag.Name</h1>
```

And used the hidden type to make a input tag containing the ViewBag an a name

```
<input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.Name" name="inpName" />
```

then in the controller I referred back to the name as "inpName".